# req.body undefined on post express nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, formidable

```html
  <form name="tld_ingest" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Application Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namel" name="namel" placeholder="Application Name">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="runall" formaction="/runAll" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm nine" style="margin-left: 40%; width: 60px; height: 35px; margin-top: 32px;" value="Run All" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputEmail4">Use Case</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="mof" name="mof">
                        <option value="s3">S3</option>
                        <option value="db">Database</option>
                        <option value="file">File</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check seven" style="margin-left:8%; margin-top:25px;">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="option2">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">
                        Ignore in-line DQ
                    </label>
                </div>
                <!-- <input type="button" id="btnloading" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm eight" style="margin-left: 23%; width: 60px; height: 35px; margin-top: 35px;" onclick="run_button()" value="Run" /> -->
            </div>

            <div class="form-row fifth" id="area3">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="line" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Line of Business</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="line" name="line" placeholder="Insights & Data">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Distributed To</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="dist" name="dist">
                        <option>EDL-WLDS</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4">Environment</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="env" name="env">
                        <option>UAT</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row fifth" id="area4">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Select Tool</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="data" name="data">
                        <!-- <option>Abinitio</option>
                        <option>Spark</option> -->
                        <option>Talend Data Fabric</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputAddress" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Source Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="source" name="source" placeholder="Source Name">
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                        <label for="inputAddress">Line of Business</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>Insights & Data</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div> -->
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputAddress" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Source Owner</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="own" name="own" placeholder="Source Owner">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-row third" id="area1">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">AWS Access Key</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="key" name="key" placeholder="Access Key">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="password" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">AWS Secret Key</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="secret" name="secret" placeholder="Secret Key">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">AWS Bucket Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bucket" name="bucket" placeholder="Bucket Name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row third" id="area2">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 ">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Key</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fkey" name="fkey" placeholder="File Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Delimiter</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="delim" name="delim" placeholder="Pipe">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="header" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Is Header Present?</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="opt" name="opt">
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row third" id="area2">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 key" style="display:none;">
                    <label for="header" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">comma separated header</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text9" name="text9" placeholder="Header Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Target Table Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text0" name="text0" placeholder="Hive Table Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Target Database Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text03" name="text03" placeholder="Database Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm third">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit"  formaction="/submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm third" style="float:right; margin-right: 37%; display: none;" value="Save & Run" />

            <div class="form-row sixth" id="area3" style="display:none;">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Line of Business</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lob" name="lob" placeholder="Insights & Data">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Distributed To</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="distr" name="distr">
                        <option>EDL-WLDS</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4">Environment</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="envir" name="envir">
                        <option>UAT</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-row sixth" id="area4" style="display:none;">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Select Tool</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="fab" name="fab">
                        <!-- <option>Abinitio</option>
                        <option>Spark</option> -->
                        <option>Talend Data Fabric</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputAddress" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Source Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="srcn" name="srcn" placeholder="Source Name">
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                        <label for="inputAddress">Line of Business</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>Insights & Data</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div> -->
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputAddress" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Source Owner</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="owner" name="owner" placeholder="Source Owner">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row fourth" id="area11" style="display:none;">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Input File Path</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1" name="text1" placeholder="Path">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">File Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text2" name="text2" placeholder="File Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Delimiter</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text3" name="text3" placeholder="Delimiter">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-row fourth" id="area11" style="display:none;">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="header" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Is Header Present?</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="arc" name="arc">
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 key cord" style="display:none;">
                    <label for="header" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">comma separated header</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sep" name="sep" placeholder="Header Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 cord">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Target Table name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="targetb" name="targetb" placeholder="Hive Name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row fourth" id="area11" style="display:none;">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="overflow-wrap: normal;white-space: nowrap;">Target Database name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="targetdb" name="targetdb" placeholder="Database Name">
                </div>

            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fourth" style="display:none;">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" id="submit1" formaction="/file" name="save_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fourth" style="float:right; margin-right: 37%;" value="Save & Run" />
```

I am trying to submit a form to database. the values does not get submitted but instead on database i get undefined. Basically my req.body is undefined and does not pass the values in.

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var http = require('http');
//var formidable = require("express-formidable");
var path    = require("path");
var shell = require('shelljs');
var formidable = require('formidable');
app.use(express.static('Project'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
var mysqlConnection = getConnection();

function getConnection() {
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        port: '3306',
        database: 'abc',
        multipleStatements: true
    });
    
}
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
    console.log("entered");
    console.log('line', req.body.line);
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    var application = req.body.namel;
    console.log("appli", req.body.namel);
    var useCase = req.body.mof;
    console.log("value in use case", req.body.mof);
    var line = req.body.line;
    var accessKey = req.body.key;
    var distributed = req.body.dist;
    console.log("distributed", req.body.dist);
    var environment = req.body.env;
    console.log("envir", req.body.env);
    var tool = req.body.data;
    var sname = req.body.source;
    console.log("source", req.body.source);
    var owner = req.body.own;
    var secretKey = req.body.secret;
    var bucketName = req.body.bucket;
    var fileName = req.body.fkey;
    var delimiter = req.body.delim;
    delimiter = '|';
    var comma = req.body.text9;
    var header = req.body.opt;
    var tableName = req.body.text0;
    console.log("fileName", fileName);
    console.log("delimiter", delimiter);
    console.log("header", header);
    console.log("tableName", tableName);
    var dbName = req.body.text03;

    var nextVal;
    var sql = 'select ifnull(max(id),0)+1 as nextJobId from talendfw';
    var query = mysqlConnection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        nextVal = results[0].nextJobId;
        console.log(nextVal);
  
        var queryString = "INSERT INTO talendfw (ID, Application_Name, t_key, t_value) VALUES('" + nextVal + "','" + useCase + "', 'line_of_business','" + line + "'), ('" + nextVal + "','" + useCase + "', 'distributed_to','" + distributed + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'environment','" + environment + "'),('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'select_tool','" + tool + "'),('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "','source_name','" + sname + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'source_owner','" + owner + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'aws_access_key','" + accessKey + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'aws_secret_key','" + secretKey + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'aws_bucket_name','" + bucketName + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'key','" + fileName + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'delimiter','" + delimiter + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'is_header_present','" + header + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'comma_separated_header','" + comma + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'target_table_name','" + tableName + "'), ('"+nextVal+"','" + useCase + "', 'target_database_name','" + dbName + "')";
        console.log("insert_query " + queryString);
        mysqlConnection.query(queryString, (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Failed to insert data" + err)
                res.sendStatus(500);
                return;
            }  else {
  console.log("Inserted the values to DB successfully. ready for next operation", results);
  shell_script(nextVal);
      }
            console.log("Operation completed");
        });
```

Please help me how to get over this issue. I used express-formidable npm and instead of req.body i used req.fields which was working fine but there is a conflict with another form data which uses formidable npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this attribute on your form element:

```html
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

That means the content type of the request you are sending is *multipart/form-data*. If you remove it the form will use the default content type, which is *x-www-form-urlencoded*. Bodyparser should be able to parse it then.

If you still want to use *multipart/form-data* (you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) question regarding what's better), you have to deal with the other form in some way.

By the way, your code might be weak to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). I would be very careful about using string concatenation when making queries. You also don't have to use body-parser to parse bodies anymore. It's been merged into Express, which means you can do

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: This helped me out.